# Please help me understand the differences between esta and está

Tags: definiciones

Please help me understand the differences between esta and está.

Answer (score 2):

#RAEconsultas «Está» es forma del verbo «estar»; «esta» es un pronombre demostrativo, que puede tildarse («ésta») si en el enunciado en el que se inserta puede interpretarse también como determinante. Si no hay ese riesgo, la tilde en el pron. demostrativo no está justificada.

https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1142064152460124160?lang=es

---

> **Mucha gente tiene dudas sobre cómo escribir y cuándo usar las palabras**
> **"ésta", "esta" y "está", que son parecidas pero tienen diferente**
> **acentuación.**
>
> No hay mucha diferencia entre las primeras dos. "Ésta" es un pronombre
> demostrativo, es decir que demuestra el punto de referencia de quien
> habla. Por ejemplo: "Ésta es la que voy a comprar" o "ésta es la que
> me gusta". Igualmente, la Real Academia Española (RAE) permite
> escribirlos sin tilde.
>
> **¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "ésta" y "esta" sin tilde?** A diferencia
> de "ésta" con tilde, "esta" es un adjetivo demostrativo. Se puede usar
> para hablar de algo que se acaba de mencionar, para algo que está
> cerca de la persona que habla, o de un período de tiempo en el que se
> encuentra quien lo menciona. Por ejemplo: "La evaluación será esta
> semana", "leé esta novela" o "en la librería compramos estas
> lapiceras".
>
> **Cómo usar "está"**
>
> Esta palabra proviene del verbo "estar", y se usa en el tiempo
> presente indicativo. Y siempre lleva tilde. Algunos ejemplos pueden
> ser: "El día está muy caluroso", "el avión está llegando al
> aeropuerto" o "¿está lloviendo?".

https://www.clarin.com/internacional/-diferencia-casos-usar_0_vxFMBs7L9W.html

---

> **Many people have doubts about how to write and when to use the words** "**esta**", "**esta**" and "**está**", **which are similar but
> have different accents.**
>
> There is not much difference between the first two. "**Ésta**" is a
> demonstrative pronoun, that is to say, it demonstrates the point of
> reference of the speaker. For example: "Ésta es la que voy a comprar"
> o "ésta es la que me gusta". ("This is the one I'm going to buy" or
> "this is the one I like.") Likewise, the Royal Spanish Academy (RAE)
> allows them to be written without accent marks.
>
> **What is the difference between "ésta" and "esta" without tilde?** Unlike "ésta" with tilde, "esta" is a demonstrative adjective. It can
> be used to talk about something that has just been mentioned, for
> something that is close to the person speaking, or a period of time in
> which the mentioner is located. For example: "La evaluación será esta
> semana", "leé esta novela" o "en la librería compramos estas
> lapiceras". ("The evaluation will be this week", "read this novel" or
> "we bought these pens at the bookstore").
>
> **How to use "está"**
>
> This word comes from the verb "**estar**" ("to be"), and is used in
> the present indicative tense. And it always has an accent. Some
> examples can be: "El día está muy caluroso", "el avión está llegando
> al aeropuerto" o "¿está lloviendo?". ("The day is very hot", "the
> plane is arriving at the airport" or "is it raining?").

https://www.clarin.com/internacional/-diferencia-casos-usar_0_vxFMBs7L9W.html

Comment: I think that "tilde" corresponds to "accent mark". Apparently it can be used in Spanish to refer to multiple diacritics, but in English isn't only the one over the n in ñ.

Comment: @Acccumulation that is correct. For some time, Spanish language teachers kept insisting that the accent mark in "á" is called a "tilde" (in Spanish) and by no means an "acento". Actually, both are correct names as DLE says, but many people still think that "acento" is wrong.

Comment: @wimi lo que sucede es que 'acento' suele usarse para indicar lo que ustedes llaman 'stress' entonces puede ocasionar confusión: todas las palabras se acentúan, pero sólo algunas llevan tilde. Otra forma para desambiguar es referirse al primero como 'acento prosódico' y al segundo como 'acento ortográfico'